# Purpose of sentinel values in merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am currently taking my first algorithms class and we have recently begun talking about merge sort. Our professor showed us the pseudocode for merge sort with sentinel values, but did not really explain their purpose. I am still fairly confused as to what purpose they serve, as one of our homework problems is to write a merge sort without sentinel values. Are there any advantages or disadvantages to including sentinel values? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just as a note, I have programmed a merge sort previously and did so without sentinel values, which is part of what has led to my confusion.

Comment: Showing the pseudocode would help.

Comment: @Aravind The *"Telling the answer won't help you."* defeats the purpose of this site, people come here for answers to specific question as this is what they need, that's how we all benefit.

Answer (score 8):

The use of sentinels in merge sort prevents us from needing to check to see if we have reached the end of either of the arrays being sorted. Merge sort can be performed without a sentinel, but an implementation of merge sort without a sentinel adds an additional check for every iteration of the comparison loop.

For example:

I'll describe this as it's described in Introduction and Analysis of Algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein, using two stacks of  playing cards to represent two arrays to be sorted.

We'll assume that both piles of cards are face-up and sorted such that the smallest card in each pile is on the top, and the largest card in each pile is on the bottom.

Let's call the left-hand pile of cards array 'L' and the right-hand pile of cards array 'R'.

For each iteration of the merge sort, we'll compare the top card on each pile and determine which is the smallest. We'll take the smallest card off of the pile, and place it face-down to create a new pile of sorted cards. This is the overarching principle of merge sort.

BUT, before we can perform a comparison between the top card on each pile, we have to make sure that there IS a card on each pile. For example, IF the cards in the left pile were consistently smaller than the cards in the right pile, we could exhaust the cards in the left pile before touching any of the cards in the right pile. In our code, this would mean as we continued to try and look at the next item in our array, we would eventually try to access an index of the array that doesn't exist, because we've already looked at all of that array's values. To protect ourselves from this occurrence, we would need to precede each comparison in the merge sort with a check to ensure that there is still a value in each array to compare.

Using a sentinel prevents us from needing to perform this extra check before each comparison by ensuring that we will never be able to remove all of the cards from one or the other pile. If we were to use 'infinity' as a sentinel value, then the 'infinity' card will NEVER get removed from the pile because no value will ever be larger than 'infinity'. This ensures that there will ALWAYS be a value in the array to compare against.

Think of the above example: where cards in the left pile are consistently smaller than cards in the right pile. Cards in the left pile will be removed one at a time UNTIL the 'infinity' (sentinel) card is reached. Then, the cards in the right pile will begin being exhausted.

At some point, BOTH piles will have their 'infinity' card on top. However, by this point, the loop counter will have reached it's maximum value, causing the loop to terminate BEFORE it can attempt to access an array index that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel values just make it so that you can do the merge in 1 for loop rather than 3 for loops. Any differences in performance or memory is tiny, and both methods are perfectly valid; use whichever you prefer.

Comment: You can easily do a non-sentinel merge with only a single loop.